# Angular validation does not work

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm following a tutorial on **`AngularJS`**, now I'm stuck, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<div ng-app="myApplication" ng-controller="ex13Controller">
        <form name="mijnFormulier" novalidate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Naam:</td>
                <td><input value="" ng-model="user.naam" name="naam" />
                <td><span style="color: red" ng-show="mijnFormulier.naam.$dirty && mijnFormulier.naam.$invalid" ><span ng-show="mijnFormulier.naam.$error.required">Moet ingevuld worden</span></span></td>
            </tr>
       </table>
       </form>
</div>
```

**Angular** shows the ***mijnFormulier.naam.$dirty*** state good, (tested when leaving the **$invalid** and the $error.required). When It comes to the validation, Angular doesn't react.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add attribute `required` to `input` tag

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
        <form name="mijnFormulier" novalidate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Naam:</td>
                <td><input value="" ng-model="user.naam" name="naam" required />
                <td><span style="color: red" ng-show="mijnFormulier.naam.$dirty && mijnFormulier.naam.$invalid" ><span ng-show="mijnFormulier.naam.$error.required">Moet ingevuld worden</span></span></td>
            </tr>
       </table>
       </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot about the required tag in the inputs. -.-

```
<input value="" ng-model="user.naam" name="naam" required/>
```

Like this.